# How to map in a React Element?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

My parameter is a array of objects. I tried to implement it but I got an error.

**Parameter 'option' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)**

I can't figure out why. Thank you for your help.

```
const options = [
  {label: 'one', name: 'one'},
  {label: 'two', name: 'two'},
]

<Checkbox options={options} />

import React from 'react'
import {Checkbox as Cb} from '@material-ui/core'
import {Field, FieldAttributes, useField} from 'formik'

interface CheckboxRecord {
  label: string
  name: string
}

interface Props {
  options: CheckboxRecord[]
}

const Checkbox: React.FC<Props> = options => {
  return options.map(option => <Field name={option.name} as={Cb} />)
}

export default Checkbox
```

Answer (score 0):

The props to a React component are *properties of the object* in the argument. Your `options` here:

```
const Checkbox: React.FC<Props> = options => {
```

isn't the options you're been passed down from above, but the *whole props* object.

Use

```
const Checkbox: React.FC<Props> = ({ options }) => {
```

Or

```
const Checkbox = ({ options }: { options: CheckboxRecord[] }) => {
```

Comment: Yes i know. I tried that version but it said: 

Type '({ options }: PropsWithChildren<Props>) => Element[]' is not assignable to type 'FC<Props>'.
  Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, keyts(2322

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:
Using React.Fragment

```
const Checkbox: React.FC<Props> = ({options}) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {options.map((option: CheckboxRecord) => (
        <Field name={option.name} type="checkbox" as={Cb} />
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```